# Is it better to create hidden elements and then show them by click or create and add to DOM by click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it better to create hidden elements and then show them by click(for example, on event)  or create and add to DOM by click using jQuery? In which case performance will be better?

```
$('<div/>', {
    'id':'createdafterhtmlloaded',
    'style':' ',
     'html':''    
}).appendTo('.cont');
```

Comment: I guess it depends on how many hidden items you intend on creating - Creating a few, probably faster to create hidden and show on click. Creating lots and lots, better to create on demand.

Comment: @Starscream1984 why so?

Comment: Upfront overhead of dynamically creating (I presume one would not hand code so many identical elements) 1000's of hidden divs that may not get shown is wasteful.

Comment: Just consider it as a matter of common sense. Which do you think will require more overhead to make something visible/invisible... to change a single property on an existing element? or to create a new one from scratch and then destroy it and have the garbage collector clean it up?

Comment: ...that said, if you're using jQuery, then you're not truly concerned about performance. Overall, that's your biggest source of extra overhead.

Comment: @squint you are absolutely right.  let's say we use pure js to add newly created code - what's then? That is about pro/cons of wasting time loading html elements `as hidden at once or wasting time creating them dynamically

Comment: @squint perhaps my question is not precise enough

Comment: @Vinand: It's a bit subjective. There's always going to be a balance of technical merit and deadlines. You can create light abstractions for both approaches *(lighter than jQuery, so close to native speed)*, so in terms of coding time, you could call it a wash. There could be scenarios where one or the other approach has unique complexities that add to the equation. But the fundamental question of performance will go to reuse of elements over creation/destruction.

Comment: ...or are you specifically talking about when the page loads? If so, it still depends on the situation a good bit. Just too hard to answer without more details. For example, creating them on the fly has the potential to reduce the data transfer to the client. But there could be other factors too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always opt for streamlining the initial load.  Depending on size, of course, once I start getting over 4 or 5 hidden elements I start to think about over loading the page.

Here's a nice article that covers hidden elements and a few other jquery optimization tips:
[javascript](http://www.punkchip.com/javascript-efficiency/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically creating brand new DOM elements will be a teeny tiny bit less efficient than switching the properties of elements that already exist in the document.

But this sort of optimisation is really only a consideration in very large, horribly complex single-page applications made from thousands and thousands of dynamic elements.

For day-to-day web development, your decision should primarily be based on what's more convenient for you, the humble, over-worked, under-paid web developer.

Comment: Spot on with "what's more convenient for you" :-)